# GUI Crop image field - Plugin request

Tags: plugins, image-transforms

I'm just wondering here if something like this is possible. On a website I'm working on for a photographer, he's in need of carefully selecting focal points on his images.

I'm aware of the focal point plugin, but that is connected to the assets file itself. And not the entry. So basically what I'm asking is

Is it possible to:

1. Upload the full source image to assets
2. On an entry, select this
   image
3. Have a separate field with a GUI control of the cropping of
   selected image from point 2.

Save the entry. And Craft takes those parameters and generates the new image and puts it in the destination folder. So the new cropped image is not in Assets at all.

The reason for this need is because the photographer wants full control of the focal points of each image.

TLDR:
Is it possible to a use something similar to [this gui control](https://github.com/engram-design/ImageResizer#cropping) on a field where an image has been selected, instead of having it directly on the assets file?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this solution: http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/120?

Vote here for better image cropping in Craft: http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7302748-intelligent-cropping-for-flexible-images

Comment: Thank you! Yes I've seen both of these solutions. The first one is the one I want, only I want some GUI to handle the cropping instead of just selecting from a drop down. I want instant visual feedback on the field.

The second one is a good request, it mentions using focal point and that would have been great! If there was some visual feedback on it.

What I would propose is an actual image field I can put anywhere, just like any other field. Which contains an image that can be selected from assets. AND a cropping control. Then, Craft would create a copy of that image.